# Loadrunner - Using and printing a parameterized value, when parameter is in file

Tags: load-testing, loadrunner

I am new to Loadrunner. I have a few values parameterized in a file type. Now I need to print the parameter value in the Loadrunner console. I tried the code below but with no luck.

```
lr_output_message("Value is %s",lr_eval_string("{Parameter1}"));
```

Error

> Action.c(15): Warning: The string 'Parameter1' with parameter
>   delimiters is not a parameter.

Please help me on this..

Comment: Please share a screenshot of your parameters for this script.

Comment: The syntax is correct. There must be something wrong with Parameter1 itself. Please post the parameterizing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the parameter is called `File1` and not `Parameter1`.

please try this:

```
lr_output_message("Value is %s",lr_eval_string("{File1}"));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help... but now if I need to use the value parameter2 inside file1... how I need to retrieve it ..

Comment: First, remove your answer below. Second - What exactly do you need to do ? Can you explain more ?

Comment: And what parameter name (left column on the parameters screen) is mapped to the column of Parameter2 inside of your file?